# R newbie having issues with lm function

Tags: r, lm

I have the following code to get the famafrench regression of a set of data:

```
#Regression
ff_reg = lm(e25 ~ rmrf+smb+hml, data=dat);
```

However, I keep getting the error "invalid type (list) for variable e25".

`e25` was defined earlier in the program as a set of data obtained from subtracting 'rf' from a matrix made up of 25 columns:

```
e25 = (dat[,7:31]) - dat$rf;
```

(where dat is an CSV file read in to R and rf is one of the columns within that file)

Why is this error coming up and how can I resolve it?

On advice, here is the full code that I am running...

```
dat = read.csv("ff2014.csv", as.is=TRUE);

##excess portfolio returns
e25 = (dat[,7:31]) - dat$rf;
#print(e25);

#Regression
ff_reg = lm(e25 ~ rmrf+smb+hml, data=dat);
print(summary(ffreg));
```

Comment: Shouldn't you append the e25 result as a new column in the dat matrix?

Comment: In a simple linear regression, you expect a single response. Sounds here like you are trying to include 25 columns as a response. That's not a simple linear model. What regressions are you actually trying to perform. You really should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we know what your data actually looks like and can run the code ourselves to see where the error is coming form.

Comment: @duffymo The e25 result is 25 columns wide, would that make it unwieldy? Also, if I do it this way, what would be on the LHS of the equals sign in the formula in the lm function?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  25 columns on the LHS makes no sense.

Comment: e25 should be a single variable. Your e25 seems like its a data frame containing 25 different variables. For regression, your dependent variable (which here is e25) should be a single column vector

Comment: @MrFlick It's perfectly valid to have a matrix on the LHS. From the documentation: "If response is a matrix a linear model is fitted separately by least-squares to each column of the matrix." Obviously, `e25` isn't a matrix, but a data.frame. Maybe all they need is `e25 <- as.matrix(e25)`.

Comment: Fair enough @Roland, it's just that's not the kind of question I expect from a self proclaimed "R newbie" that doesn't even explicitly mention the intention to fit multiple models with different responses.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the help guys, it is much appreciated, I'll go with Roland on this one as it seems to be giving me the results I need/want. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `help("lm")`:

> If response is a matrix a linear model is fitted separately by least-squares to each column of the matrix.

So, if that's what you intend to do, you need to make your data.frame a matrix before you call `lm`:

```
e25 <- as.matrix(e25)
```